# Java: Reading in an image from same folder as java files

Tags: java, file-io, javax.imageio

I have code that reads in an image file from the same directory as the java files, but currently I can only get it to work if the entier path is given.

```
picture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\...\\ogre.png"))));
```

The image is in the same folder as the java files. But when I try just `"ogre.png"` or `".\\ogre.png"` or similar it does not work.

My question is this:

1. I will be exporting to a JAR eventually, will this affect that once the jar is created? (I'm assuming yes, since creating a jar doesnt change the source code).
2. How can I read the file from the same folder instead of the exact file path, In a situation where the containing folder were to be moved for example.

Comment: You need to put yourself in the shoes of an end user of the application. All the end user has is a jar file containing the application. No java source file at all. Where should the application read the images? Are they supposed to be images belonging to the end user, and sitting on the end user's hard drive? Or are they supposed to be delivered and embedded with the application?

Comment: Try `getClass().getResource(...)`

Comment: @JBNizet the images are predefined and probably will be within the jar file itself

Comment: Then you must NOT use file IO to load them. You must use the class loader, to load them from the classpath, just as classes are loaded from the file system (during development) or from the jar file (once bundled). `new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/com/mycompany/myapp/images/ogre.png"))`, assuming the png file is in the package `com.mycompany.myapp.images`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard way... (and it will work when everything is in the jar)

```
URL url = OneOfYourClass.class.getResource("package/pathTo/image/ogre.png");           
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
```

`OneOfYourClass` is a class that you have (maybe the main class)

`package/pathTo/image/` is the path from this class to find your image

Comment: if the image file is in the same folder should the path be nothing? as in `"ogre.png"` sorry! ament used to reading i files with java

Comment: @Jack Moulson  yes, but i would in general suggest that you start to use package...

Comment: Ah it is in a package called `softdev`, so that would make the path `"softdev/src/ogre.png"`?

Comment: @Jack Moulson you have a package called src??? normally your code is in a folder called src (and this is base)... the path is the relative path form the class you are using as loader..

Comment: @Jack Moulson If you have doubts put the png with the class (same folder) you use to load it with and do as you indicated in first comment

Comment: sorry yes my mistake `softdev` is within src so: `"softdev/ogre.png"`

Comment: No. `"/softdev/ogre.png"`.